# What happens if I shake a magnet in terahertz scale?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

I was wondering, if I theoretically shake a magnet like a sine wave with a very high frequency (Let's say a frequency in visible spectrum), will I see a visible light coming out of it?

Comment: you mean shaking an electron and its magnetic moment?

Comment: Shaking a magnet isn't a particularly effective way to get it to radiate, but if you *spin* a magnet...

Comment: The way you make radio waves is to shake electrons up and down an antenna. At higher frequencies this makes microwaves. If you continue this, you would get visible light. Electrons have intrinsic spin and magnetic moment. So yes.